# Activating CKEditor blocks comment submission by visitors to WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, ckeditor

using WordPress 4.5

Very simple...activate CKEditor and you get a "you are submitting too fast, please wait a few minutes" whenever you try to submit a comment anywhere on the website...deactivate CKEditor...comments work just fine.

Also, not too crazy about having to cut and paste into a "security box" to actually add text to a page or post, but I can live with that, but this is just way too much!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/its-not-working-on-wordpress-43

see if you are lucky enough to find the solution on this page